# how to consume message from specific offset using Kafka HTTP Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Confluent HTTP Sink Connector to consume the message from Kafka topic, by default it read all the messages from beginning. I've use case where I want to stop the connector for some time and resume the HTTP sink connector later. When I resume the connector I want to read the message from specific offset.

I was looking offset related configuration here https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-http/current/connector_config.html but I couldn't find any.

How can I consume the message from specific offset?

Answer (score 0):

All (at least most) sink connectors use Kafka Consumer groups.

You can use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` command to first seek the group for the connector to specific offsets. And then, when it starts again, it should begin to read from that position.

> by default it read all the messages from beginning

Not necessarily. By default, `auto.offset.reset=latest`